# Convert a torchscript model into Core ML

Tags: python, torch, coreml, coremltools, detectron

I am trying to convert a Detectron 2 model into Core ML. I have scripted it and now I have a model of type 'torch.jit._script.RecursiveScriptModule'. If I try and convert it into Core ML using this code:

```
mlmodel = ct.converters.convert(
  torchscipt_model,
  inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=(1, 3, 64, 64))],
)
```

I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Unknown type bool encountered in graph lowering. This
> type is not supported in ONNX export.

I scripted the model using the following code (as illustrated in Detectron's [documentation](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4/modules/export.html))

```
model = build_model(cfg)
model.eval()

fields = {"pred_boxes": Boxes, "scores": torch.Tensor, "pred_classes": torch.Tensor, "pred_masks": torch.Tensor, "proposal_boxes": Boxes, "objectness_logits": torch.Tensor}

torchscipt_model = scripting_with_instances(model, fields)
```

Do you know any other way to convert my Detectron2 model into Core ML?

Thank you so much for your help!